# Kafka Streams: "Updated cluster metadata version" runs for a very long time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For the last hours, my Kafka Streams job tries to spin-up but is occupied with `Updated cluster metadata version` for a very large topic:

```
2018-01-03T13:30:56.871 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer] - Starting the Kafka consumer
2018-01-03T13:30:56.882 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata] - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [node2:9092 (id: -2 rack: null), 
  node3:9092 (id: -3 rack: null), node1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
...
2018-01-04T10:10:27.945 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] - Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=<ALL>) to node node3:9092 (id: 3 rack: null)
2018-01-04T10:10:27.952 DEBUG [org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata] - Updated cluster metadata version 704157 to Cluster(id = DmwzpJYRTEGrm8MfjcpXLw, nodes = [node3:9092 (id: 3 rack: null), 
  node1:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), node2:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 9, leader = 3, replicas = [3], isr = [3]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 8, leader = none, replicas = [2], isr = []), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 7, leader = 1, replicas = [1], isr = [1]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 6, leader = 3, replicas = [3], isr = [3]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 5, leader = none, replicas = [2], isr = []), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 4, leader = 1, replicas = [1], isr = [1]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 3, leader = 3, replicas = [3], isr = [3]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 2, leader = none, replicas = [2], isr = []), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 1, leader = 1, replicas = [1], isr = [1]), 
  Partition(topic = raw-messages, partition = 0, leader = 3, replicas = [3], isr = [3])])
```

It's a new Kafka Streams job with a new application id and it's supposed to start from the very beginning (offset = 0).

There are several events which probably caused this behavior:

- we migrated from Confluent Platform 3.2.0 to Confluent Platform 4.0.0
- the Kafka cluster crashed hard due to a power outage in the data center

My question is, should I let it run? Currently, the job is at `metadata version 704157`, can I find out or estimate the total number of version?

Comment: `876649` and counting ...

Comment: `1451669` - will it ever end?

Comment: This indicates, that the internally used consumer cannot find the leader for a partition... You should check the health of your Kafka cluster. Compare partitions 8,5,2 report `none` for leader -- thus the consumer is stuck until it can find the leader.